# Workload Scheduler: What is the purpose of table EPR_ENDPOINT_REFS?

Tags: workload-scheduler

I'm using the Workload Scheduler v8.6 and I see that the table size of some tables in DB2 are very large. 
I'm trying to understand if I can prune the size of EPR_ENDPOINT_REFS
manipulating some of the keys in JobDispatcherConfig.properties.
Is It possible to compress it's space utilization further? where the
table is loading its data from?

Answer (score 0):

the DWB.EPR_ENDPOINT_REFS table is used by broker component to store data useful for contact agent. 
It is linked to DWB.JOB_BROKER_JOBS table and for each dynamic job stored in this table, some information are stored in the DWB.EPR_ENDPOINT_REFS.

When dynamic jobs data are deleted from DWB.JOB_BROKER_JOBS table, automatically the data stored in the DWB.EPR_ENDPOINT_REFS are cleaned up.

In the JobDispatcherConfig.properties file, stored in the /TDWC/config, two properties define when jobs are deleted from DWB.JOB_BROKER_JOBS:

- SuccessfulJobsMaxAge (default 10 days)
- UnsuccessfulJobsMaxAge (default 30 days)

About the space compression, it is not directly related to TWS configuration.

Best regards,
Daniela